# Class method that sort a list of objects with a comparator given as parameter (Java)

Tags: java, sorting

I´m having troubles to define a method that sort a list of the same class where is defined this method.

For example the class is defined with the following attributes:

```
          public abstract class Licence {
            //other attributes
            protected List<People> myList;

            //Constructor and other methods

            //The method I want
            public List<People> getPeopleInOrder ( Comparator c)
              List<People> aux = new ArrayList<People>(this.myList); 
              Collections.sort(aux, c);
              return aux;
```

And also I have this class

```
                class CompPeople implements Comparator<People>{
                public int compare( People e1, People e2) {
                // Declaration the criteria of comparison
                if ( c1 == 0) {
                     if (c2 == 0 ) return c3;
                   else return c2;
                }
               else return c1;
        }
    }
```

But when I call in main method

```
               List<People> myNewList = Mylicence.getPeopleInOrder(new CompPeople());
```

EDIT: Before I was trying to sort a unmodifiable list, I changed it and now it gives me empty list.

I know I can use the method sort of Collections but what I want is a method of class Licence that sort its list with a given comparator. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Am I correct in understanding that you are trying to sort an unmodifiable list?  (Also, please [edit] your question to include any and all errors you are getting.)

Comment: Also, "it fails" is too unspecific, please give a proper "failure" description when asking questions. In this case, "throws an UnsupportedMethodException" (IIRC).

Comment: No, my intention was to pass a copy of the list but now I´m not sure if it works

Comment: @daniu ok edited with the error , sorry

Comment: One you've gotten answers, please don't edit the question to become about a different problem you have after using those answers. It's confusing, and wastes people's time.

Comment: @ruakh the last and unique edit was 52 min ago and I only changed that I was passing a unmodifiable list, but the problem in esence is the same : how I can declare a method that do what I say in the question. Anyway, I´ll keep it in mind next time I do a question, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have incorrect comparator.

Let define a `People` class:

```
public class People {
    private String name;
    private String city;
}
```

In case you plan to use different ways to compare these object, then it is better to use custom comparators. E.g. this is two comparators that sort people by one of the field. I recommend to define different comparators as part of `People` class:

```
public class People {

    private String name;
    private String city;

    public static final Comparator<People> SORT_BY_NAME_ASC = (one, two) -> one.name.compareToIgnoreCase(two.name);
    public static final Comparator<People> SORT_BY_CITY_ASC = (one, two) -> one.city.compareToIgnoreCase(two.city);

}
```

Now you can use it sort `List<People> peoples`:

```
people.sort(People.SORT_BY_NAME_ASC); // sort by name asc
people.sort(People.SORT_BY_CITY_ASC); // sort by city asc
people.sort(People.SORT_BY_NAME_ASC.thenComparing(People.SORT_BY_CITY_ASC));    // sort by name and city asc
```

---

You method `getPeopleInOrder()` could look like this:

```
public List<People> getPeopleInOrder(Comparator<People> comparator) {
    if(myList.isEmpty())
        return Collections.emptyList();

    List<People> aux = new ArrayList<>(myList);
    aux.sort(comparator);

    return aux;
}
```

...or using `Streams` like this:

```
public List<People> getPeopleInOrder(Comparator<People> comparator) {
    return myList.stream().sorted(comparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

---

In case you want only one comparator, then you have two ways.

#### class People implements Comparable

```
class People implements Comparable<People> {

    private String name;
    private String city;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(People people) {
        int res = name.compareToIgnoreCase(people.name);
        res = res == 0 ? city.compareToIgnoreCase(people.city) : res;
        // compare other fields you want
        return res;
    }
}
```

#### Use single Comparator

```
public class People {

    private String name;
    private String city;

    public static final Comparator<People> SORTY_BY_NAME_AND_CITY = (one, two) -> {
        int res = one.name.compareToIgnoreCase(two.name);
        res = res == 0 ? one.city.compareToIgnoreCase(two.city) : res;
        // compare other fields you want
        return res;
    };
}
```

Comment: But what about if `People` has 3 attributes or more and I want to use all that attributes to sort `People` objects? Can´t I have a single `Comparator<People> ` object that compares by differents attributes of `People`?

Comment: Just one more question, in case I use the options of `only one comparator` what I have to pass as argument to `getPeopleInOrder`?

Comment: `getPeopleInOrder(People.SORTY_BY_NAME_AND_CITY)`

Answer (score 0):

As you should be able to guess from the comment, the problem is the `unmodifiableList()`. For a copy, just create a new `List`.

```
public List<People> getPeopleInOrder ( Comparator c)
    List<People> aux = new ArrayList<>(this.myList);
    Collections.sort(aux, c);
    return aux;
}
```

Comment: Yes Ive changed it, but now it returns me a empty list

Comment: @UnknownUser Then `this.myList` is also empty.

Comment: So the way I was using the comparator is right and the problem is only that?

Comment: @UnknownUser Without the complete code, I can't possibly tell you. The Comparator method you post is definitely incomplete (as it's not declaring any of the `cX` variables, but that shouldn't result in an empty list if no other errors occur.